# In Django, how do I update a user profile if a model is added to database?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm creating a site where users can upload files. I have my upload form working, and it correctly associates the current user with the uploaded file. Once it's uploaded however, I would like the User Profile model to update the number of files uploaded for that specific user.  I'm using django-allauth with a custom admin model.

models.py (works to recognize current user)

```
class ConfigFiles(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)

    Printer = models.CharField(_('Printer Model'),
    max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, unique=False, help_text="Something like 'i3'")
    printerbrand = models.CharField(_('Printer Brand'),
    max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, unique=False, help_text="Something like 'Prusa'")
    Plastic = models.CharField(_('Plastic'),    
    max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=False, help_text="Something like 'ABS' or 'Nylon'")

    HDConfig = models.FileField(_('High Detail, Slow Speed'), 
    upload_to=UploadedConfigPath, validators=[validate_file_extension], help_text="Displayed as HD on Infinity-Box")
    LDConfig = models.FileField(_('Fast speed, Low Detail'), 
    upload_to=UploadedConfigLDPath, validators=[validate_file_extension], help_text="Displayed as FAST on Infinity-Box")

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(_('date_joined'), 
    default=timezone.now)
```

And here's my custom admin models.py (doesn't auto update configuploaded)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(DemoUser, primary_key=True, verbose_name='user', related_name='profile')

    avatar_url = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)

    configuploaded = models.IntegerField(_('Number of uploaded Config files'), default=0, unique=False)
    filesuploaded = models.IntegerField(_('Number of uploaded STL files'), default=0, unique=False)


    dob=models.DateField(verbose_name="dob", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return force_text(self.user.email)

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'user_profile'
```

**EDIT 1**

Here's view.py.

```
@login_required
def uplist(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConfigUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user
            #newdoc = ConfigFiles(HDConfig=request.FILES['HD file'])

            comment.save()


            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "Configuration added")    

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('list'))
    else:
        form = ConfigUpload()  # A empty, unbound form
    print (request.user.first_name)
    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = ConfigFiles.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render(
        request,
        'visitor/configupload.html',
        {
        'documents': documents,
        'form': form,
        }
    )
```

Ideally, whenever the user uploads a file the configuploaded variable increase correspondingly. Is there a simple way to do this within models or should I do if from my views.py?

Comment: You can update the user field in your views. Can you show the related views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a few ways to solve this, how best to go about it depends on your use case. In my current site I use a mix of properties and signals to acheive this functionality.

Using a property - less db writes works & even if you execute bulk deletes on a model, but generates a query everytime you display it.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    #your stuff
    def _get_uploaded_files(self):
          return ConfigFiles.objects.filter(some_appropriate_filter).count()
    uploaded_files = property(_get_uploaded_files)
```

Override the save method to increment your field:

```
class ConfigFiles(models.Model):
#your model definition here
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConfigFiles, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user.filesuploaded += 1
```

You can also use the postsave signals as per Atul Yadav's answer. However IMO they are somewhat less clear (because you end up defining functionality outside of the model) although they are useful if you need to do several things

Comment: When I run this i get an error 'def _get_uploaded_files:' invalid syntax. I assumed Blog is the app name so I changed that but I left everything else.

Comment: Blog is my mistake,  I copied it out if an existing app. answer is edited

Comment: Since I have a custom Auth model I have to make a few adjustments. I got everything running without error, but its not quite correct. Now my superuser can't upload anything, but upload works for the normal user.  The normal user can upload files, however they aren't being tracked and the upload count doesn't rise above 0

Comment: @rknrobin what method are you using? The first shouldn't have any issues with your auth model as it just counts relations (assuming you have corrected model names etc) is the doe actually running? Do you have autocommit enabled? If not swap the order of the increment and super().save() lines

Comment: I'm using the default autocommit, so it's enabled. I've been debugigng and the save method calls the correct variable. The issue (i think) is in the _get_uploaded_files on the return call. Since my models are in separate files I can't import ConfigFiles without getting a circular import error.

Comment: OK, so there are two problems here. One is that you should be using one or other of these, not both. One sets the variable on upload, (or on edit - you'll need to catch that if you allow the model to change) the other calculates it dynamically. A way round the import is to use the related managers. So your call becomes something like self.configfiles_set.count()

Comment: Alright I understand it better now. I have got (only) the _get_uploaded_files function mostly working but I am having issues with my filter() command. I'm not sure how to call my user (a ForeignKey) to pass the current user, but I can correctly select other Char variables. Any Idea how I can change the filter command to point at the user ForeignKey?

Comment: You need to either select the user object, probably user = self in this context, or if that doesn't work because of your custom model user.somedistinguishingid=self.somedistinguisher

Comment: Got it to work with user = self. I'm new at programming and this was a complicated question thanks for all the help!

Comment: no problem, do bear in mind that this hits your database everytime you access that parameter, that will get slow fast if you intend on displaying it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Post Save Signal in Django

```
from django.db.models.signals import *
from django.db.models import F

def file_upload_count(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.filter(user = instance).update(filesuploaded = F('filesuploaded')+1)

post_save.connect(file_upload_count, sender=ConfigFiles)
```

Whenever a new file is uploaded this will perform the function defined and will increment the value or whatever u want.

Try adding this code in your models file

Comment: This gives me the error that 'ConfigFiles' is not defined.

Comment: Try pasting it in end of your model file. You can search more about Django post save signal

Comment: Posting this at the end of my code gives me an error that "name 'UserProfile' is not defined". I was under the impression importing the user also brought user profile data, but I'm not sure. I will look more into post save signal

Comment: If both these models are not in same file then you need to import it in this file.  Imorting user does not imports the coustom user porfile one

Comment: I imported the UserProfile but now I'm getting this error 'Cannot query "ConfigFiles object": Must be "DemoUser" instance.' I have a custom admin and I think it might be messing some things up.

Comment: Because of my custom auth model, Calling the "user" command doesn't grab the model and i need to replace it with "profile" If i replace the instance I get the error that "Cannot resolve keyword 'profile' into field. Choices are: avatar_url, configuploaded, dob, user, user_id". I'm unsure if the instance is what I should have replaced, or something like the objects.filter()?

Comment: As users in both models are not same. One is using demo user other is using settings auth try using same in user. Instance is the common feild in both model which is unique.